# Need help optimizing vba display function

Tags: excel, vba, performance, function

I have been doing some database work with excel both as the database and the database driver via macros with vba. I built a function that should parse through a list of database records with testID fields. I wanted to display each test only once based on it's testID, but the way the database is set up means I have to eliminate duplicate testID's. I do this by iterating through the recordset and checking the current test against the previous one before showing in the list. The problem I'm having is that the function is excruciatingly slow. For only 12 tests in the database, it takes about 3 seconds to display them in the view spreadsheet. I'd love to hear some ideas on how to optimize the run-time. Here's the function:

```
Public Function showAllTests()
Dim conn As ADODB.Connection
Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
Dim cstring, sql As String
Dim r, c As Integer
Dim testsAr As Variant
Dim inAr As Boolean

cstring = "Provider = Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source=I:\DBtrials.xlsx; Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0 Xml; HDR=YES;ReadOnly=False"";"

sql = "SELECT [TestID], [Status], [PFIBox], [WireType], [StartingDia], [Customer], [numSamples], [Assigned] FROM [Tests$]"

Set conn = New ADODB.Connection
Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset

Call conn.Open(cstring)
Set rs = conn.Execute(sql)

If rs.EOF Then
    Range("C6:J1000").ClearContents
End If

r = 6
count = 0
'Iterates through the recordset, eliminating duplicates and populating cells in the tests sheet
While Not rs.BOF And Not rs.EOF
        Dim prevID, currID As String
        Dim currCell As Range

        inAr = False

        If Not count = 0 Then
            prevID = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Tests").Cells(r - 1, 3).Value
            currID = CStr(rs(0))
            If prevID = currID Then
                inAr = True
            End If
        End If

        For c = 3 To (rs.Fields.count + 2)

            Set currCell = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Tests").Cells(r, c)

            If Not IsNull(rs(c - 3).Value) And inAr = False Then
                currCell.Value = CStr(rs(c - 3))
                ElseIf IsNull(rs(c - 3).Value) Then currCell.Value = ""
                    Else:
                        Exit For
            End If
        Next c

        If inAr = False Then
            r = r + 1
        End If
        rs.MoveNext

        count = count + 1
Wend



conn.Close
Set conn = Nothing
```

End Function

Answer (score 1):

use GROUP BY

sql = "SELECT [TestID], [Status], [PFIBox], [WireType], [StartingDia], [Customer], [numSamples], [Assigned] FROM [Tests$] GROUP BY [TestID]"

Also some of these drivers  -  Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0 etc have terrible perfomance in VBA.  sometimes i get better perforamance from OBDC 6.2 than ADO